# Best approach to translating numerous email templates

Tags: email-template, bestpractice, translation

**The Problem:** I have approximately 30 different email templates that are being sent out to applicants during an application process. Applicants have 3 language options: English, French & Portuguese.

**The Question:** What is the best approach to translating these email templates when they are sent to an Applicant?

The most obvious option is to manually create 1 email template for each language, but that's a lot of work and not easy to keep updated. Any other suggestions?

**Note:** I'm not sure how Visualforce will help here since that would require a lot of custom labels and not be helpful when it comes to formatting. It's also not easy for non-dev users to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy solution here.  A 3rd party app like [Conga Composer](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer) might help you reduce the number of templates you have to maintain, but you'll still need to maintain the different language content in some way, probably in custom labels or possibly custom metadata.